# HTTP 401 Error When Trying to Deploy Spring App via Gradle and Jenkins on a Tomcat 7 Server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jenkins, gradle

I'm doing my best to make this up as I go, so feel free to point out any and all stupid things you see.  I've installed Tomcat 7 (on a machine running OS X Mavericks) and changed the port from 8080 to 80, so I can just use `http://localhost/app`.

Everything above functions properly if I simply drop my .war file in the `/webapps` directory.  I then downloaded Jenkins and placed its .war file inside `/webapps` as well, allowing me to access the web interface at `http://localhost/jenkins`.

My plan was to use Jenkins to pull my repo from bitbucket, build it, and then deploy it to the Tomcat server.  The cloning and building portions work flawlessly, but deploying is a different story...

Here's the log from Jenkins:

```
:processResources
:classes
:war
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 14.437 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
Deploying /var/root/.jenkins/jobs/MyApp/workspace/build/libs/workspace.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/root/.jenkins/jobs/MyApp/workspace/build/libs/workspace.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:195)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:504)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:622)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:635)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:176)
    ... 16 more
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:504)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:622)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:635)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:176)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I were to guess, I would say the issue lies within my `tomcat-users.xml` file.  I have tried every combination and permutation of roles, users, etc. that were suggested elsewhere.  Just for reference, here's what it looks like now:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-script”/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script”/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Most of the other questions refer to Maven plugins and such, but even sifting through those provided me with no real solutions.

Comment: I am not familar with jenkins deploy plugin, but according to documentation it uses cargo, and for cargo you should specify remote user and password. Did you specify the parameters?

Comment: Also, try to add another roles to your user: admin-script and maybe manager-gui. Also, could you check the url from your browser, are your credentials work fine from browser?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk, thanks for the reply. I specified the parameters in the `tomcat-users.xml` file. Oddly enough, when I add `manager-gui` as a role, I get a 403 error. Is there a different place to specify these?

Comment: "I specified the parameters in the tomcat-users.xml file." It's on the tomcat side, i mean did you specify username and password on jenkins side! Jenkins tries to access tomcat by urls and can't authorize itself if you didn't tell him what credentials to use.

Regarding roles and usernames tomcat-users is a right place. What i mean is to add all possible roles:
 <tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-script”/>
  <role rolename="admin-script”/>
  <role rolename="admin”/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script,admin-script,admin”/>
</tomcat-users>

Comment: I've specified this on the Jenkins side properly (at least I think so) as well. I updated my `tomcat-users.xml` to include all that you've provided, to no avail - I still get the same error in the log.

Answer (score 0):

```
401 means "Unauthorized".
```

1. Try to check your credentials.
2. Last time when I deploy my app to Tomcat7 I use this link:

   ```
   localhost/manager/text/html
   ```
3. Can you deploy this app without jenkins only using gradle ?
4. Very simple (temporary) solution is (if you deploy app on the same machine) is to copy war in Tomcat **${catalina.home}/webapps** directory. When war is copied Tomcat expand this to desired url. Then you need to restart is to be sure that all caches is clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we simply had to update the Jenkins deploy plugin.